# Cannot see in registry for .Net framework 4.5.1 on Windows7 SP 1

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework-version

I have installed .Net framework 4.5.1 on Windows7 sp1. I can see in the Control's panel program list but I cannot find the folder named "full" in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0`). There is only client folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I see, halfer. Thank you for correcting.

Comment: I can see the .Net framework 4.5 now. Thank you all.

Comment: have you checked my answer? Do you see the entries?

Comment: Yes, magicandre1981, I saw it under v4, Full. Thank you

Comment: if you get the answer you wanted, [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `4.0` entry is obsolete, use the `4`. So check under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`.

[image]

Here look for `Release` values to see the [version + patchlevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_b).